# Python Caesar break

Tags: python, python-3.x, decoding, encryption

We'll generate decryption alphabets for each of the 26 possible keys.

I got that part done but I can't get it to print out the word that is in the dictionary.
for example:i only want 'ebv' to print hey

how do i match it to the word in the dictionary instead of printing out all 26 possible keys.

here's the dictionary: http://www.ics.uci.edu/~kay/wordlist.txt

```
Alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'  

def rotated_alphabet(key:int) -> str:
    '''produces a rotated alphabet based on key and adds those letters to the end of alphabet'''
    if key > 26:
        key = key % 26
    new_alphabet = ''
    w = Alphabet[0:key]
    x = Alphabet.replace(Alphabet[0:key], new_alphabet)
    return (x + w)

def Caesar_break(cipher:str) ->str:
    infile = open('wordlist.txt', 'r')
    wordlist = []
    possible = []
    decode = []
    words = []
    for str in infile:
        t = str
    for i in range(0, 26):
        p = rotated_alphabet(i).split()
        possible+=p
    for y in possible:
        decrypt = str.maketrans(y, Alphabet)
        decode.append(cipher.translate(decrypt))
    for str in decode:
        s = str
        words.append(s)
    print(words)

Caesar_break('eby')
```

it prints out:

```
['ebv', 'dau', 'czt', 'bys', 'axr', 'zwq', 'yvp', 'xuo', 'wtn', 'vsm', 'url', 'tqk', 'spj', 'roi', 'qnh', 'pmg', 'olf', 'nke', 'mjd', 'lic', 'khb', 'jga', 'ifz', 'hey', 'gdx', 'fcw']
```

Comment: **What have you tried**? Where are you stuck?

Comment: is `def Caesar_break(cipher:str) ->str:` valid Python?

Comment: @hayden: yep, although it's not very useful here.  See [PEP 3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#fundamentals-of-function-annotations) and the [ref](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions).

Comment: @Anony-Mousse this is what I got so far and i tried to get it to print only 'hey' but it always comes out blank so I went back to how it was before.

Comment: I need help to match one of the results to a word in the dictionary.

Comment: @DSM Thanks! (I missed the Python3.x tag.) Interesting!

Comment: Well, right now you discard all the words you read from the word list. Why don't you try storing them in a dictionary and see if any rotated word matches?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse that's the problem.  I know that 'hey' matches with 'hey' in the dictionary but i don't know how to print out just that word. and How do i store them in a dictionary.(sorry my instructor is teaching a couple of chapters behind so the lab is really hard for everyone because we have to do self-study from textbook)

Comment: How about looking in the textbook for "dictionaries"?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I found it in the textbook but it's a chapter ahead of what the lab asked for so I don't know if it'll count

Comment: you can also use sets, lists, whatever you prefer then I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The canoncial approach to solving this is:

1. Read all lines from the word list and insert them into a dictionary `dict`
2. Try the various ceasar rotations via `translate`
3. If a rotation produces a word from the dictionary (`decrypt in dictionary`), output it

For longer texts, you might want to check if e.g. at least half of the words are found in the dictionary. Pay attention to lowercase/uppercase issues and *newline* characters etc! - try using `strip`!

A more advanced approach would do character statistics, and guess the proper rotation based on this statistic.